# how to get value of BTC (in USD) when transaction was made on a wallet

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

in old blockchain when when we hover cursor on amount it used to show value when transaction was made (sent/recieve) after update OCT 2019 the value keep changing accourding to current BTC price. is there any Endpoint or any other explorer with with we can check value of each transection when it was made.

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1JT8wK9PzASF623Af2GD4ZprEHHYMCWdzY

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can still see the value of USD when the transaction was made you need to click on the transaction hash and you see the TX Details and old value, the change was that when you hover with cursor it shows you actual value.

Comment: TY. i missed that